# Where can I ask a question about ancient siege weapons?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have some interest in Medieval battles and sieges, and I want to ask a question about siege weapons like trebuchets and catapults (from the view of history). Since the question would be more focused on how they worked and less on how they developed, I have considered the following sites:

- [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/) has a [middle-ages](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middle-ages) tag and a [weapons](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons) tag
- [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) *seems* to be a better place because I'm interested in how exactly it works, but I can't find a relevant tag.

I'm a bit confused because I don't want to cross-post, which itself is considered a bad practice on SE.

Comment: The [Quora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora) of Stack Exchange, *[Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour)*, has heaps of (hypothetical) questions about this. [Sample](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/61322/what-difficulty-would-the-roman-empire-have-besieging-a-fantasy-kingdoms-49-m-w/61384#61384).

Comment: There is a regularly reoccuring [A51 initiative about weapons & military](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102381/weapons), if you are interested in the topic, please don't forget to support/start/restart the relevant concept on the A51. It is not enough if you think it would be useful to have such a site, *you have to represent this need with your votes, too*.

Answer (score 5):

## I'd say History.SE is fine.

From my experience - which is, admittedly, not a lot (2 questions) - I'd say that History.SE would accept it as on topic (it's about history) and they'd be more familiar with the objects and therefore know more about how they worked, as they're historical things and more in their place of expertise than a bunch of physicists.

Physics.SE - which I'm not so familiar with - would probably be able to tell you how the catapults moved through the air and the science behind them, but I don't think that they'd tell you how they were put together etc. You also say that you're interested in it *(from the view of history)*, so that implies that your questions would probably better on History.SE as well.

Comment: As a Physics mod, I'd agree that History is a more likely place to start. I can't say without seeing the question, but many things you'd want to ask about catapults would be either off topic or duplicates on Physics.